# Hold the same unique pointer in two data structures

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I want to hold a unique_ptr to the same object inside two data strucutres, is there any way I can do that or I should consider using different method?

In my case I have a map to support fast searching and I also want to keep references to the keys & values in two other data structures.. (Say list)

I would really love to hear some advice from more experienced C++ developers , or maybe an alternative to Unique_ptr.

Thanks in advance

Comment: unique_ptr only works if you have one (unique) reference to the class. Alternatives are the shared_ptr (with weak_ptr combo) that does the reference counting to keep your class alive.

Comment: If you hold a unique pointer in two places, it is no longer unique :-)

Comment: hehe ofc that is true, so must I use shared_ptr instead?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But that’s not actually what the `unique` in `unique_ptr` means – the name is misleading. More accurate would be `unique_ownership_ptr` but it’s easy to see why this name wasn’t chosen. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Say I want to hold a unique_ptr to the same object inside two data strucutres, is there any way I can do that

Yes, absolutely! Now, `unique_ptr` conveys *unique ownership* semantics – but nothing says that you cannot hold a reference to it from elsewhere as well. Just be aware that only one object can *own* it, the other data structure must by necessity be subjugate. As a consequence, that object should always have a shorter life-time than the object owning the unique pointer, in order to avoid invalid memory accesses.

Now you just let one object hold the `unique_ptr<T>` and the object holds a raw `T*` that points to the first object’s address (obtained via `.get()`).

If that situation cannot be realised in your case, then `unique_ptr` isn’t the right tool – use `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: May be the pointer obtained with `.get()` should be assigned to a `T const*` member for such a situation?

Comment: @g-makulik No, why? Depending on the situation it’s entirely fine to get a raw pointer to a mutable object.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Would enforce RAII, wouldn't it? Anyway, it's OK to use raw pointers obtained with `.get()`, didn't wanted to state it isn't.

Comment: @g-makulik I think I misunderstood your comment because I don’t see how it relates to RAII.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry, you're right! It doesn't enforce RAII. I think I've confused with needs for initialization of valid `const` references. It's different for pointers no matter if these are declared `const` or not.